# After Effects - Trying to Export Video with RGB Alpha (I get a black background in the export)

Tags: video, after-effects, export

In After Effects I'm trying to Export Video with RGB Alpha (I get a black background in the export) please see notes below:

Here's my setup (on canvas transparency is toggled on)
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: have you viewed the video that you rendered in an application that is aware of alpha channels (e.g. after effects?). Most video players don't show alpha as transparent (ask yourself how they would do this—show the desktop through the player? Checkerboxes like potatoshop?), but as black. Import the file into after effects and see whether it contains transparency.

Comment: ^ This. Can you try to re-import the finished video into Premiere or After Effects, drop a color matte behind it to verify that the background output was indeed black?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work to me. You could try using ProRes 4444 instead, with millions of colours+ and Alpha turned on.